# Windows 8 tiles apperance in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-8, desktop-environments, customization, appearance

Is it possible to have Windows 8 - like tiles in Ubuntu Unity or other desktop environments,where your tiles act as links to applications?

[image]

Comment: Have a screenshot, or description of what you mean by "windows 8-like tiles"? Like animated pictures? Or random news clips that update occasionally? And do they have to be links to applications?

Comment: All of these answers miss what is coolest about the tiles, that they update, are resizable, groupable, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the gnome desktop.

Screen shot of what I think you're after based on your question: 
[image]

You can find Ubuntu Gnome here: http://ubuntugnome.org/

You can also add gnome via the Ubuntu Software Center by searching for "gnome."

Answer (score 1):

take a look at these gnome themes:

1. [devianart eight](http://flatmo1.deviantart.com/art/EIGHT-start-page-UPDATE-212847573) : see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRWA474KTWY)
2. [windows8 Style](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/+%28windows8++Style%29+0.1+Sigma+metro?content=167327) 0.1 Sigma metro 0.1 GNOME Icon Theme
3. [Windows 8 modern UI](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=158721) (metro) Gtk3 (+Gtk2) 0.4  GTK 3.x Theme/Style

Answer (score 1):

One more option with **Cairo Dock** and Sigma metro 0.1 GNOME Icon Theme as Kamil suggested :

(In Cairo Dock configuration I chose **Slide View** and changed Icon theme, edited icon size)

[image]